# which embedded web server to use for my app GUI

Tags: c++, embeddedwebserver

I'm writing an application in c++ and I was thinking to use an embedded simple web server that will be my gui, so i could set up my application port on localhost.

What such web server would you recommend to use in c++/c?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using boost then rolling your own in [boost:asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) is simple.

I assume by **embedded** you mean a built in webserver not that you are running on some tiny embedded hardware.

If you want something simpler look at [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) - also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738273/open-source-c-c-embedded-web-server

Answer (score 1):

I use [C++ Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) for these kind of interfaces

Answer (score -3):

You are aware that a lot of machines already run something on port 80/443, are you?
[edit]
Controlling an embedded system sounds like a good fit for snmp, not http.

Comment: Generally simple page to control application running in specialized embedded machine isn't bad idea, right? Even if you have running some Server on port 80, it's just be faster to post command to embedded server on other port. And communication thought other external server is some times 2x work to do.

Comment: I think he was talking about an embedded web server, not an embedded system.

Comment: embedded web server on application software not hardware