# C/C++ - Any good web server library?

Tags: c++, c, webserver, embeddedwebserver

Are there any open source, fast web server libraries? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738273/open-source-c-c-embedded-web-server, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205753/which-embedded-web-server-to-use-for-my-app-gui

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) (formely [shttpd](http://shttpd.sourceforge.net/), GPL v2 and commercial license), [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) (LGPL v2.1 license).

Comment: libmicrohttpd is just perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link to libmicrohttpd, I had no idea it even existed :) Looks like a clean API and very liberal license, its going in my tool box.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-1.4.10/) has a great event-driven and lightweight http server [header](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-1.4.10/evhttp_8h.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very bare bones, but interesting stuff.

Comment: Bare bones is actually what c++ code should be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with the concept you can check [this codproject article.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/webem.aspx)

You can also check [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers) whcih compares major light weight embedded server.

You can check [**AppWeb Http Server**](http://www.appwebserver.org/) also.

Answer (score -6):

Take a look at Qt. I don't know if it's fast enough for you, but it has a nice network module. You also get SQL and XML modules, and a lot more (which can be nice depending on your needs), for free. GPL/LGPL and cross-platform.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtnetwork.html

Comment: Qt network library doesn't give you a way of handling http protocol. It also doesn't come with a thread pooled select server. You would have to construct everything from TCP up to an http server capable of handling the [C10k problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). As such, I do not find this recommendation useful.